# Search View close button is hidden

Tags: android, searchview

When In android's default `SearchView` I am setting iconifide as false then the close button of `SearchView` is hidden.

**Requirement:** `SearchView` should be by default open when `Activity` launched and the close button should be visible;

```
 searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultActivity.class)));
 searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

first way you can do this

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)  
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setFocusable(true);
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

or there is another way

```
     @Override
            public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

            try {
                Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mCloseButton");
                searchField.setAccessible(true);
                mSearchCloseButton = (ImageView) searchField.get(mSearchView);
             if (mSearchCloseButton != null) {
                 mSearchCloseButton.setEnabled(false);//  mSearchCloseButton.setEnabled(false);
                 mSearchCloseButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent));
             }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error finding close button", e);
            }
        }
```

for more detail [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930380/android-search-widgethow-to-hide-the-close-button-in-search-view-by-default),[link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710042/expand-and-give-focus-to-searchview-automatically)