# Android Toolbar in webapp

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a web app, and here I have a problem.

I have a tool bar(android widget toolbar) with logo and search button

As you can see I have the login page(webview). I want to user to see this search button after users login to the webpage. How should I do that?

[image: Toolbar]

Edited:

In my toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In my menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

And in MainActivity.java onCreate,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.logo9);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```

......

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And finally in activity_main.xml, I just include the toolbar,

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
```

Comment: Hi, try this and let me know it works or not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930380/android-search-widgethow-to-hide-the-close-button-in-search-view-by-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the search button is an Android `View`, you can hide it by calling `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

If you have instead defined it as a `menu` XML resource and loaded it in this `Activity`, then just don't load the `menu` resource unless the user is logged in. That is done in `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` of the `Activity`.

If you go to another `Activity` after logging in, then just use a separate `Toolbar` there, with the icon like here, but without one in the login `Activity`.

Please provide more information on how you added the search icon to the `Toolbar` in the first place, then I will be able to help you more.

**Edit:**

You can use the `WebView.getUrl()` method to get the URL of the displayed website, if your login page is on `login.php`, you can look if the URL is that, and then not show the search icon. For example you can check the URL with `String.contains()`, like: `.contains("login.php")`. And if that is true don't show the button.

Comment: But then how do I write the if statement for user login status? like if user is in logged session then show the search button. How should I write it in MainActivity.java??

Comment: Because login is not a part of activity in android. It is done in my website.

Comment: if (!url.contain("login")) { getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu_main, menu); and following scripts. I didn't write else statement and then return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); } This didn't work.

Comment: Is the login URL actually containing "login"? Does the search icon disappear when you comment out the entire `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: Yes, when I remove onCreateOptionsMenu() the search icon disappeared.

Comment: Well then there is no reason why it shouldn't work if you wrapped it in an `if` statement. Try `Log`ging the URL returned by the `WebView` to see if it's like you think it is.

Comment: I tried many times but it seems like it is not working. What actually mWebView.getUrl() outputs? for example, does it output string value of "http://asdfasdfafs.com/login/"? if the current url is that?

Comment: Like I said, it would be best for you to just try outputting whatever `getUrl()` returns and see in LogCat what is it. Or you can use the debugger to make a breakpoint before `getUrl()`, you can then use the "Evaluate expression" button to execute any code you want and see it's output. You can use that to see what methods return.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles for this activity use this attribute in your style for this activity

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```